# Using find to delete files with same names from two directories

Tags: linux, find

I have a nightly job to delete all files from a specific folder that have not been touched in 2 weeks.

This command works perfectly for that:

```
find /dir1 -type f -name '*.json' -mtime +15 -print -delete
```

Now I have a new requirement. There is another directory /dir2 where there are files with the same names as in /dir1 (may exist or not). They hold different contents and I don't care about their last modified time.

I just want the file names that are being deleted from /dir1 to be also deleted from /dir2 at the same time (if they do exist in /dir2)

Is it possible to do in a one liner? Or will I need to write a Python script for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is:

- first you list the files that you want to delete

  > `find /dir1 -type f -name '*.json' -mtime +15 -print > toBeDeleted`
- then you delete them in dir1 and potentially in dir2 by doing this `rm` in the two directories

  > `xargs rm < toBeDeleted`

Comment: Yes, I had to add `-exec basename {} \;` to the find command to print out only the basenames. Then `cd` into each directory one at a time and do the `xargs rm` thing. I was hoping there would be a neat little way to do this, but apparently not. Thanks for your advice anyway!